# Block TOR Servers

Tags: php, apache, module, centos, tor

I need a script that blocks `TOR servers` in `php` ... I need to get the list of servers and block them.

Or, any solution to install on the server (centos).

Answer (score 10):

Here is more information about TorDNSEL https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en  and how to structure query.

And below is function I found on the net that can perform dynamic checks.

( https://check.torproject.org/ must use something similar to this ).

I am not sure about performance under heavier traffic.

```
function IsTorExitPoint(){
if (gethostbyname(ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).".".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].".".ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org")=="127.0.0.2") {
return true;
} else {
return false;
} 
}
function ReverseIPOctets($inputip){
$ipoc = explode(".",$inputip);
return $ipoc[3].".".$ipoc[2].".".$ipoc[1].".".$ipoc[0];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to check if the user's ip is in a TOR exit node DNSBL. Using static exit node lists won't be a good idea since nodes appear/disappear from time to time and you probably won't want to update the list regularily.

Various blacklists exists, the [EFNET RBL](http://efnetrbl.org/) is one of them. Note that it also resolves for some other IPs that might be considered undesirable in some cases - if you just want TOR ensure to ignore those other results.

Comment: great!, I will investigate this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Maxpower, I don't quite get how the EFNET RBL works.  Is there someplace on the site to download the list?  I don't see the link.

Answer (score 0):

If its need to block the TOR User id, follow the method:

```
ipset -N tor iphash
```

get a list of Tor exit nodes that can access `$YOUR_IP`, skip the comments and read line by line

```
wget 

ipset -q -A tor $IP

done
```

filter our new set in itables filter

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set tor src -j DROP.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/RD17/DeTor)(https://github.com/RD17/DeTor) is a simple REST API to determine whether a request was made from TOR network or not. I think it will be pretty simple to use it from PHP

The request is:
`curl -X GET http://detor.ambar.cloud/`.

The response is 

`{ 
  "sourceIp": "104.200.20.46",
  "destIp": "89.207.89.82",
  "destPort": "8080",
  "found": true 
}`

As a bonus you can add a badge to your site to detect whether a user comes from TOR or not:

`<img src='http://detor.ambar.cloud/badge' />`