# Protecting admin panel with secret HTTP header - is it foolish?

Tags: php, security, http, authentication, admin

I was just thinking of additional protection for my admin panel. I could send some HTTP header, let's call it `Mushroom-Token` with some long value. When it's not in the request or when it has invalid value, my admin panel would throw 404 all over.

That would be, of course, only additional layer of protection. When this token is valid, user still needs to log in as an admin.

Does this method make any sense? Isn't that an example of security through obscurity? Or maybe it's widely used technique? And, finally, what are some other ideas of additional protection for admin panel?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I want to prevent any potential brute force trials. I want to hide my form structure from people who are not intended to be allowed there.

Comment: Adding a header does nothing to prevent brute force attacks.

Comment: Im not agree PeeHaa, if he logs ppl dont have the header, with access time, and IP, he can easily prevent many brute-force attacks

Comment: When I hide a form entirely, I protect my API from guessing attacks, because they won't even send proper fields names and won't know the URL to send brute forces to. Plus, those trials will fail anyway, because without that token you are not even able to log in, even with valid credentials. Is my thinking pattern wrong?

Comment: Yes it is wrong because it false security. Anybody who knows about the header can use it. So you only *think* you made something more secure while you only have hidden it from *some* people. Once anybody knows the token and the header nothing stops him/her from sharing it using it him/herself for malicious intends. The way to stop brute force attacks is by making it slow enough (throttling, captcha etc) to make it infeasible. trying to hide it and failing to do so is useless.

Comment: Sometimes I'm thinking whether this false security idea is not kinda misunderstood. If you think this way, you can easily interpret entire login + password idea as false security as well. It's just about knowing this combination - what's so different about that?

Comment: Once the guy find the header (this will take a long time if the key is hard and if you block IP once 10 times wrong header / key), he still have to find user + password, with same limits, this is too long, and too hard, and most of hackers will not try many times before trying another way.

Comment: The difference being protecting a single account (including an easy way to reset the credentials) and trying to protect all requests.

Comment: You don't seem to understand a word I have said :| @Bob0t

Comment: @PeeHaa but this header wouldn't be even publicly known. I mean: neither its name nor value. Isn't it harder to find out about security step that is totally unknown than about a value of known pattern? (like form's login and password). Please don't take it as an offence, I really enjoy this discussion, but for me it looks like you follow those dogmas a little blindly. I'm waiting for more argumentation, please don't go away :)

Comment: How on earth can said header not be public when the client actually needs to send it?

Comment: Yes, but you can have YOUR client configured to send this header. It's not public at all, it's like password saved in your browser.

Comment: [Yes but what is prevent me from sharing the header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888692/protecting-admin-panel-with-secret-http-header-is-it-foolish?noredirect=1#comment61342772_36888692)

Comment: Why would I share it? Do you go and share your passwords with your friends? :D

Comment: Reading this discussion, I want to add the header *could* be used as a single use key, if the key is unique each time and tracked via a Database or smiilar, very much like CSRF blockers on forms, while this *could* be done I think that there are probably much more succinct ways of doing what you're trying to achieve. Also please look into [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) as a similar (but different) headers topic you should be aware of.

Comment: The header token would also need to be saved as a SESSION value on you server side so that you can fairly independently cross check it *each time*. If you don't do this, then it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Martin, I dont't understand this idea with storing token in session. I thought of having it checked on each request, within my app middleware.

Comment: I think it will be worth your time @RoboRobok to do a google and the read up about CSRF and how to prevent it, as this is essentially the same methodology you're trying to employ here. This should also give you a glimpse into sessions and why you should be using them (at least on a cursory basis) .

Comment: Martin, I know perfectly what CSRF is, but I don't see any connection here. I want to prevent brute forces, not request forgery. Those behaviors are different.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to prevent brute force attacks is by making it slow enough that brute forcing is just not feasible.

This can be done in several ways (assuming online attacks):

1. throttle attempts by rate limiting attempts on accounts
2. add a captcha on multiple incorrect login attempts on accounts
3. add a captcha on multiple incorrect login attempts on the system as a whole
4. block ips on multiple incorrect login attempts system wide (this will not prevent much because attackers can easily get their hands on a lot of accounts)

You idea of using a token in a header imo won't work because of several things:

- The token is pretty much public, because the client side has to have it
- Once any of your clients shares the token everything is lost
- Once any of your clients go rogue anything is lost
- Once a token is used maliciously used there is no easy way to reset the token and pass it on to the non malicious clients

You are talking about an admin panel so I assume and web interface to some backend. That would involve browsers. There is no easy way for you to tell browsers they need to add said header to the requests they are going to make.

The above assumes you are going to use a single token for all clients. This means you only need a single malicious user and again everything is lost.

If the above assumption is wrong and you are going to provide every client with a unique token you would have the problem that the clients somehow need to get the token first (which should be based on authentication which leaves you with a catch 22 situation). This also means that only a single user will be able to use a specific client because at that point the token is bound to both the client as well as the token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm already sorry for my poor English, I hope you will understand what I m trying to tell you.

With this kind of 'security' I think you can prevent some session hijacking attacks. But there is a lot of other ways to do it, like regenerating session ID, setting user IP into session (then you have to check if last IP is the same as current IP), etc ...

If you want it safer, you can also set it as only accessible from SSL & some IPs.

You can add things like anti-bruteforce protections by checking how many times an IP access your admin panel without the secret header / with a wrong header value. And then block IP's that are retrying too much in a period of time ...

Ah yes, and adding full logging of admin panel accesses & actions can be great to check if an attack succeeded.

Finally, most attacks are done server-side, I mean, if you have an old apache, nginx, php version, etc ... if you let open ports to everyone ... I'm unable to list all possible attacks. So securing your script is something good, but don't forget the rest.

I hope this will give you reflection ways.

**EDIT**

I seen you want to prevent bruteforce attacks, the first layer is server side, with kind of proxy or firewall, like HAProxy which is able to block too many connections in a short amount of time (this will slow down the bruteforce, and prevent your database to be accessed too much)

You should also use strong passwords : 
- min 10 chars
- 1 maj, 1 min, 1 figure, 1 special char (like @, !, # ...)

I would disallow TOR [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13912957/3799829)

PHP exemple

```
function IsTorExitPoint($ip = null)
{
    if(is_null($ip))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $stuff = ReverseIPOctets($ip) . "." . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . "." . 
             ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) . ".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org";

    if (gethostbyname($stuff)=="127.0.0.2")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function ReverseIPOctets($inputip)
{
    $ipoc = explode(".",$inputip);
    return $ipoc[3].".".$ipoc[2].".".$ipoc[1].".".$ipoc[0];
}

if(IsTorExitPoint($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
    // do disallow stuff
}
```

Comment: Prepending header names with `X-` is actually deprecated and the link you have shared clearly states it :)

Comment: Ahaha, that's seems true, I'm out of date :') gona read it taking my time (answer updated)

Comment: That's interesting though, I didn't know anything about this `X-` convention. I've just seen it here and there, but now I know it's not recommended. Thanks!

Comment: well I didn't known it was not recommended anymore, so thanks to you, I did not re-read this answer for a long time :D

Comment: So we have a win-win! :D

Comment: Your strong password definition is incorrect. Passwords don't need to contain any types of characters, they simply need to be long -- HorseBatteryFarmLifeGoat is a far, far more secure password than X34_ghtr5Ma1$

Comment: Martin, I think it's not black or white situation. It all depends on the type of guesser. As far as I know, many of them start from guessing words and words combinations. Keeping that in mind, for those guessers, the latter passwords is harder.

Comment: @RoboRobok no. Don't base a security method on who you think will try and compromise it. There are various reports that state all that adding symbols to passwords does is confuse the human who should be logging in, rather than making longer, wordier passwords the human can remember and statistically less likely for a guesser device to breach.

Comment: A 13 digit password with a character set of 128 characters is 2.4e^27, whereas a 20 digit password from the same character set *even if it doesn't use those characters* is 1.3e^42, that's over a thousand billion times more secure. Every character set that has a-z also has $ and ! etc etc, they're worthless as password strengtheners .

Comment: @RoboRobok google them,. But the cartoon I posted also shows the same thing rather more concisely.

Comment: The cartoon you posted doesn't make for any proof. I can draw cartoon to illustrate the opposite. I'm not saying you are wrong, but so far I don't see any proof.